# Hbase Json file data store

Tags: json, hbase

I created a HBase table with a column family named `cf` which I store under it a Json file in a column qulifier named `value` so it look like this `column=v_cf:value`.  When I store data as a json file I get the following :

```
    column=cf:value, timestamp=1428482891760, value={
\x0A  "Status" : "Available",
\x0A  "id" : 23001\x0A}
```

I want to know what does `\x0A` means? is it relative to Hbase? and how could I delete it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the hexadecimal equivalent of line feed(\n). You can refer [this](http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html) for more of such characters. It might be added when you have pressed Enter or new line into your json file/input.

Comment: the link does not appear

Answer (score 2):

It is new line character`(\x0A)`. you can use `json.replace("\n", "")`  before storing to `hbase`.